# How to get dynamic home page

Tags: php, html, css, web

I  have a index.html file consist of certain data with refresh button.

On pressing refresh button it will call refresh.php.

Refresh.php connects database and gets new updated data from database (Say- today's event data) And shows updated data in that refresh.php page

this is what I do.. But I want dynamic home page and want to remove refresh button. In short- whenever user loads homepage..that division should display updated data from database. So should I  use .index.php and use php code in index.php itself will work?

I dont want to use asp/ajax/cookie/session. Please give me idea apart from these. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried 'index.php'?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. But I want another method if any :)

Comment: Another method? Like what? Any other method is (probably) wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You could check the file's age, e.g.

```
<?php
$ca_file = '/path/to/foo.blah';

if (is_file($ca_file)) {

    // check if file is not older then 1 hour
    if (time() - filemtime($ca_file) <1 * 3600) {
        $ca_news = 'y';
    }
}
```

That would check if the file is not older then 1 hour. You'll probably want something smaller. Now all you need to do is to check the value of $ca_news and do your magic.